# Overriding a layout file in magento2 is not working

Tags: magento2, layout, overrides, override-block

What I want to override:

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml
```

I copied the file to this location:

```
app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[MyCustomTheme]/Magento_Catalog/layout/override/base/catalog_product_view.xml
```

I commented out the product.info.details block:

```
<!--block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.details" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/details.phtml" after="product.info.media">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.description" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getDescription</argument>
                    <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
                    <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
                    <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Details</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attributes.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                <arguments>
                    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">More Information</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </block -->
```

I still see the block on my products page.  I believe I followed every direction found here (using magento 2.2.4): `https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-override.html`

I then performed these cli operations:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Why am I not seeing any changes?

Comment: Did you get your answer !

Comment: No, I did not.  I was using a Pearl theme from Weltpixel and it appears that was why I was not able to extend or override files according to the guides.  I'm new to stackexchange, what should I do to close out a question like this?

Answer (score 3):

This is the correct path for it:

```
app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[MyCustomTheme]/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml
```

Add this code on the `catalog_product_view.xml` if you want to remove the product info details

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details" remove="true">
```

Comment: Thanks Jake for the answer, is your answer considered extending rather than overriding?  I have tried your method.  It did not work for me so I installed a fresh copy of magento 2, extended the luma theme and added the `Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`  layout file.  I used the `referenceBlock` in your example to remove `product.info.description`, `product.info.sku` and `product.info.overview`.  Nothing changed on my product page.  The description, sku, and description overview blocks are still on the page.

Comment: Yes, I believe this is a form of extending and not overriding. The overriding documentation is [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-override.html) and it does not seem to be working.