# Overriding "base" layout not working

Tags: magento2, layout, overrides

I'm reading the documentation [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-override.html). My goal is to remove the "Customize and Add to Cart" button, for a bundled product

[image: customize-add-to-cart-bundled-button]

The path for the layout can be found here `/vendor/magento/module-gift-registry/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view_type_bundle.xml`. I want to remove the first action

```
<action method="setGiftRegistryTemplate">
    <argument name="blockName" xsi:type="string">customize.button</argument>
    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_GiftRegistry::product/customize.phtml</argument>
</action>
```

which meets the criteria in the documentation for overriding a layout file

> Examples of customizations that involve overriding layouts:
>
> - Suppressing method invocation.

Note there is no method to cancel the prior invocation in the Block class itself. So I have added this file in my custom theme

`/app/design/frontend/vendor/theme-name/Magento_GiftRegistry/layout/override/base/catalog_product_view_type_bundle.xml`, duplicating the stock layout file and omitting the first action (referenced above).

There is no change on the frontend, the button is still there. I found [this thread](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/229874/overriding-a-layout-file-in-magento2-is-not-working), however the original question was not answered, and I'm looking for an answer to that very question now.

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I found that both the layout override and extension were needed. Per both Satish and Roman, the layout extension

```
<referenceBlock name="customize.button" remove="true" />
```

is needed in

`app/design/frontend/vendor/theme-name/Magento_Bundle/layout/catalog_product_view_type_bundle.xml`

However the layout override in

`app/design/frontend/vendor/theme-name/Magento_GiftRegistry/layout/override/base/catalog_product_view_type_bundle.xml`

is also needed, because without it Magento tries to call `setGiftRegistryTemplate` on a block that does not exist!

Comment: So finally it has been resolved. It is strange that layout override also needed in your case because in my case it was worked with extended layout only. I did not override it.

Answer (score 2):

Briefly, you're overwriting wrong layout :)

1. "Customize and add to cart" button is originally created in Bundle module:

   [vendor/magento/module-bundle/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view_type_bundle.xml:76](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4.0/app/code/Magento/Bundle/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view_type_bundle.xml#L76)

   ```
   <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
       <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="customize.button" as="customize_button" template="Magento_Bundle::catalog/product/view/customize.phtml" after="product.info.price" />
   </referenceContainer>
   ```

   It shows [button text](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4.0/app/code/Magento/Bundle/view/frontend/templates/catalog/product/view/customize.phtml#L14) as:

   ```
   <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Customize and Add to Cart')) ?></span>
   ```
2. GiftRegistry module merely replaces above block template if condition is met

   ```
   return $this->getRequest()->getParam('options') == self::FLAG; // flag = "giftregistry"
   ```

   Replaced template `Magento_GiftRegistry::product/customize.phtml` has another button text:

   ```
   <button id="bundle-slide" class="action primary customize" type="button"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Customize and Add to Gift Registry')) ?></span></button>
   ```

So your code actually works, it disables gift registry change, but original Bundle module button is not affected.

Test with such URL: https://example.com/catalog/product/view/id/52?options=giftregistry

As mentioned before, you don't need override in this case, `<referenceBlock name="customize.button" remove="true" />` works (tested).

P.S. You can peek at layout merge/override process using debug here:

- [Magento\Framework\View\File\Collector\Base](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4.0/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/File/Collector/Base.php#L58)

  `<modules>/view/base/layout/*.xml`

  `<modules/view/frontend/layout/*.xml`
- [Magento\Framework\View\File\Collector\ThemeModular](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4.0/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/File/Collector/ThemeModular.php#L76)

  `<theme>/*_*/layout/*.xml`
- [Magento\Framework\View\File\Collector\Override\Base](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4.0/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/File/Collector/Override/Base.php#L87)

  `<theme>/*_*/layout/override/base/*.xml`
- [Magento\Framework\View\File\Collector\Override\ThemeModular](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4.0/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/File/Collector/Override/ThemeModular.php#L88)

  `<theme>*_*/layout/override/theme/*/*/*.xml`

Source: [magento2-exam-notes](https://github.com/magento-notes/magento2-exam-notes/blob/master/3.%20Customizing%20the%20Magento%20UI/1.%20Demonstrate%20ability%20to%20utilize%20themes%20and%20the%20template%20structure.md#layout-file-source)

Comment: The canonical answer I was looking for, thank you sir. I will award the bounty in a few hours when stack exchange allows it.

Comment: OMG I botched the bounty assignment!!

Comment: It happens, never mind 

Comment: Hooked you up brother, thanks for your time!

Comment: WOW you are the best! Thanks again 

Answer (score 0):

You can create an XML file in your theme same as the given path:

```
app/design/frontend/vendor/theme-name/Magento_Bundle/layout/catalog_product_view_type_bundle.xml
```

and put below code in that file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customize.button" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: I tried this, it does not work. Probably, because the block is added as an action, not via layout. Can you stick to the question at hand please? Why is the override not working as the documentation states?

Comment: That is the path for layout extension, per [the documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-extend.html)

Comment: Yes, it will extend the layout instead of override. have you try with changing argument blockName to false?

Comment: I am trying to understand how to _override_ a layout. The question has been asked previously and not answered, hence I am curious for an answer. I am not interested in a workaround.

Comment: Ok, I have also checked overriding other layouts like customer account edit and cms page view and that works fine. Have you confirmed that the file is not  in the blank or luma theme. If your parent theme is blank then do not need to check luma theme.

Comment: I don't see the file in blank or Luma, here is output from `find` command: ```./vendor/magento/module-gift-registry/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view_type_bundle.xml
./vendor/magento/module-bundle/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view_type_bundle.xml
./vendor/magento/module-bundle/view/adminhtml/layout/catalog_product_view_type_bundle.xml
./vendor/magento/module-instant-purchase/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view_type_bundle.xml```